# Span and Div Tags in Accordions

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some accordions that use `<span>` for the content toggling and they work.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/castonzo/dVbkL/3/)

But I am violating a HTML 5 DOM rule that states that a `<div>` cannot be nested within a `<span>`

Any suggestions? Thanks

```
     <! -- TAB #1 -->
  <div class="accordion-tab">Tab #1<a class="btn blue">Edit</a></div>
    <span>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="wrap">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque blandit aliquam malesuada. 
                </p>
             </div>
        </div>
    </span>
  </div> 
   <! -- TAB #2 -->
  <div class="accordion-tab">Tab #2<a class="btn blue">Edit</a></div>
    <span>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="wrap">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque blandit aliquam malesuada. 
                </p>
             </div>
        </div>
    </span>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".accordion-tab").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('span').find('.content').not(':animated').slideToggle();
        });

    });
```

Comment: You can't (or at least shouldn't) nest block elements inside inline elements, but you can use divs for the wrappers and either float them or set them to inline-block

Comment: What's the question? Are you asking for another way to do this? Or about violating HTML 5 rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can do exactly the same things changing span by div

```
<div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="wrap">
```

and

```
$(this).next('div').find('.content').not(':animated').slideToggle();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dVbkL/4/

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any `div` nested inside of `a`.

`<div class="accordion-tab">Tab #1<a class="btn blue">Edit</a></div>`

You have an `a` nested inside of a `div`.  A-OK.

Answer (score 0):

Do you even need the span in this case? Try removing the span tags altogether, or changing them to divs with float.